# pytest-xdist fails to collect tests after identifying workers

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, pytest, pytest-xdist

I am unable to figure out why pytest=xdist is failing to collect tests from the `tests/sqlalchemy-dialect-compliance` folder after it finishes identifying workers. We have used the tests in that folder for years with no problem if we simply use `pytest`, but as soon as we add `pytest-xdist`, all collection fails.

I am attempting to run tests on a Linux box (48 cores) in a docker container using pytest and `pytest-xdist` to get parallelization across the CPUs.

I can get `pytest/pytest-xdist` to recognize the right number of workers. But it never collects any tests no matter what settings I have and what I do.

I have tried many different settings in various combinations (using settings for `dist`, `tx`, `numprocesses`, etc). The most recent is as follows:

```
nox > py.test -s -vvv --dist=each '--tx 4*popen//python=python3.11' --numprocesses=4 tests/sqlalchemy_dialect_compliance
=== test session starts =============================================================
platform linux -- Python 3.11.6, pytest-8.0.0, pluggy-1.4.0 -- /repo/github.com/googleapis/python-bigquery-sqlalchemy/.nox/compliance/bin/python
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: /repo/github.com/googleapis/python-bigquery-sqlalchemy
configfile: setup.cfg
plugins: xdist-3.5.0, rerunfailures-13.0
4 workers [0 items]     
scheduling tests via EachScheduling

=== no tests ran in 0.51s ============================================================
nox > Command py.test -s -vvv --dist=each '--tx 4*popen//python=python3.11' --numprocesses=4 tests/sqlalchemy_dialect_compliance failed with exit code 5 # No tests collected.
nox > Session compliance failed.
```

with `numprocesses=auto`, it recognizes all 48 cores:

```
48 workers [0 items]
```

I have tried this with Python 3.11 and 3.12.

Comment: Just to be clear: you have verified that the tests are correctly collected without `pytest-xdist`, right?

Comment: @MrBeanBremen great troubleshooting question. Yes... this test suite is one we have used successfully for years. We are now looking at whether adding `pytest-xdist` might speed up the execution of the test suite.

Comment: Yeah, covering the bases... I just have no idea. I guess that you have already tested with another pytest version (8.0 came out only a couple of days ago), but I don't really think that this will change the outcome. And I guess no chance for a reproducible example...